# Delphi via XML-RPC to C++

Tags: c++, delphi, xml-rpc

Need to create C++ XML-RPC server on windows and connect to it from client that is created on Delphi 2007. For server I took open source project http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/competitor.php. And for Delphi client side I took library http://sourceforge.net/projects/delphixml-rpc/ . I have done simple programming on both sides and after execution I got only one record in log file that was don by library on server side:

```
10.1.1.55:56581 - no_user - [01/Apr/2014:17:51:55 -0300] "POST" 404 535
```

Client side reported that connection is dropped.

I have no idea how to deal with this error. Is there any debuging methodology when creating RPC applications from different environments?

Delphi side code:

```
function RPCCreate(ObjectMethod: String; var RpcCaller:TRpcCaller; var RpcFunction:IRpcFunction ): boolean;
begin
    try
    Logit('RPCCreate '+ObjectMethod+' '+RPC_HostName+':'+inttostr(RPC_PortName) );
    RpcCaller := TRpcCaller.Create;

    RpcCaller.HostName := RPC_HostName;
    RpcCaller.HostPort := RPC_PortName;

    RpcFunction := TRpcFunction.Create;
    RpcFunction.ObjectMethod := ObjectMethod;

    result:= true;
    except
    result:= false;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm4.doRPC;
var
  RpcCaller: TRpcCaller;
  RpcResult: IRpcResult;
  RpcFunction: IRpcFunction;
  p : integer;
begin

try
if RPCCreate('sample.add',RpcCaller ,RpcFunction ) then
begin


    RpcFunction.AddItem(10);
    RpcFunction.AddItem(20);


    RpcResult := RpcCaller.Execute(RpcFunction);


//    if RPCisErr(RpcResult) then result:= jeRPCGenericErr
//    else
//    if RPCisInteger(RPCResult,fRes) then result:= jeNone else result:= jeRPCNoExpectedInteger;

    RpcCaller.Free;


end ;
except
on e: Exception  do
    begin
    logit('err');


    end;
end;


end;
```

C++ server side code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef WIN32
#  include <windows.h>
#else
#  include <unistd.h>
#endif

#include <xmlrpc-c/base.h>
#include <xmlrpc-c/server.h>
#include <xmlrpc-c/server_abyss.h>

#include "config.h"  /* information about this build environment */


#ifdef WIN32
  #define SLEEP(seconds) SleepEx(seconds * 1000, 1);
#else
  #define SLEEP(seconds) sleep(seconds);
#endif


static xmlrpc_value *
sample_add(xmlrpc_env *   const envP,
           xmlrpc_value * const paramArrayP,
           void *         const serverInfo,
           void *         const channelInfo) {

    xmlrpc_int32 x, y, z;

    /* Parse our argument array. */
    xmlrpc_decompose_value(envP, paramArrayP, "(ii)", &x, &y);
    if (envP->fault_occurred)
        return NULL;

    /* Add our two numbers. */
    z = x + y;

    /* Sometimes, make it look hard (so client can see what it's like
       to do an RPC that takes a while).
    */
    if (y == 1)
        SLEEP(3);

    /* Return our result. */
    return xmlrpc_build_value(envP, "i", z);
}



int 
main(int           const argc, 
     const char ** const argv) {

    struct xmlrpc_method_info3 const methodInfo = {
        /* .methodName     = */ "sample.add",
        /* .methodFunction = */ &sample_add,
    };
    xmlrpc_server_abyss_parms serverparm;
    xmlrpc_registry * registryP;
    xmlrpc_env env;

    //if (argc-1 != 1) {
    //    fprintf(stderr, "You must specify 1 argument:  The TCP port "
    //            "number on which the server will accept connections "
    //            "for RPCs (8080 is a common choice).  "
    //            "You specified %d arguments.\n",  argc-1);
    //    exit(1);
    //}

    xmlrpc_env_init(&env);

    registryP = xmlrpc_registry_new(&env);

    xmlrpc_registry_add_method3(&env, registryP, &methodInfo);

    /* In the modern form of the Abyss API, we supply parameters in memory
       like a normal API.  We select the modern form by setting
       config_file_name to NULL: 
    */
    serverparm.config_file_name = NULL;
    serverparm.registryP        = registryP;
    serverparm.port_number      =8080;// atoi(argv[1]);
    serverparm.log_file_name    = "c:/tmp/xmlrpc_log.log";

    printf("Running XML-RPC server...\n");

    xmlrpc_server_abyss(&env, &serverparm, XMLRPC_APSIZE(log_file_name));

    /* xmlrpc_server_abyss() never returns */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well clearly the client asked the server something it doesn't recognize (ending in a 404 response).  As you didn't include source code, that's about all I can say with a reasonable degree of certainty.

Comment: @user1501700 could you find where the problem is?

Comment: No, I vent another way